# How to compile a simple boost program from command line in unix

Tags: c++, boost

Say I have the path to the headers and lib files of boost, in `$BOOST_INLCUDE` and `$BOOST_LIB`.

How do I build a simple hello world?

Answer (score 7):

Add them with -I and -L parameters.

```
g++ helloworld.cpp -o helloworld -I"$BOOST_INLCUDE" -L"$BOOST_LIB" -lboost-whatever-lib-needed
```